# IBM IIB Mapping Complex Type Element to String

Tags: xsd, xml-parsing, ibm-integration-bus

I'm attempting to create a map for the following message in IIB Integration Toolkit 10.0.0.3 mapping tool:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns0:Envelope xmlns:tns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns1="http://NewPublishingXMLtoACORD" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <tns0:Header/>
    <tns0:Body>
        <tns1:operation1>
            <DOCUMENT TYPE="RPWIP" VERSION="12.3">
                <DOCSET NAME="">
                    <LIBRARY NAME="" CONFIG="99999montp">99999montp    </LIBRARY>
                    <ARCEFFECTIVEDATE NAME="CREATETIME">20160830    </ARCEFFECTIVEDATE>
                    <KEY1 NAME="KEY1">2014 FOMRS</KEY1>
                    <KEY2 NAME="KEY2">COMMON POLICY FORMS</KEY2>
                    <KEYID NAME="KEYID">99999999    </KEYID>
                    <TRANCODE NAME="TRANCODE">NB    </TRANCODE>
                    <STATUSCODE NAME="STATUSCODE">N    </STATUSCODE>
                    <DESC NAME="DESC">Created by tests harness    </DESC>
                    <LOCID NAME="LOCID">99999    </LOCID>
                    <SUBLOCID NAME="SUBLOCID">0    </SUBLOCID>
                    <JURISDICTN NAME="JURISDICTN">NY    </JURISDICTN>
                    <TRNNAME NAME="TRNNAME">Test Harness    </TRNNAME>
                    <QUEUEID NAME="QUEUEID"/>
                    <GUIDKEY NAME="GUIDKEY">0CA1E753FEF54BD0A372FC0D1306E498    </GUIDKEY>
                    <FIELD NAME="policyNumber">MQ12414698-000    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="effectiveDate">06/29/2016    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="expirationDate">06/29/2017    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="namedInsured">LSB PF - test</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="dba">Test Body Shop    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="insuredAddressLine1">1234 N. Main St.    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="insuredAddressCity">Bronx</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="insuredAddressState">NY</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="insuredAddressZip1">06100</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="agentNumber">99999    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="agentName">99999 MP House Account    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="agentAddressLine1">123 Main St</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="AGENTADDRESSCITY">Phoenix    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="agentAddressState">AZ    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="agentAddressZip1">98732    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="taxState">NY</FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="businessDescription">My business description    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="premiumProperty">16,909.00    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="premiumCrime">18,750.00    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="countersignedDate">08/30/2016    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD NAME="LSS_STAMP">
                        <P ALIGN="JUSTIFY">
                            <FONT STYLE="FONT-SIZE: 10pt" FACE="Helv">This </FONT>
                        </P>
                        <BR/>
                    </FIELD>
                </DOCSET>
            </DOCUMENT>
        </tns1:operation1>
    </tns0:Body>
</tns0:Envelope>
```

I'm having issues mapping the DOCUMENT/DOCSET/FIELD node. I need to map each of these elements based on the attribute name but I'm unsure of how to accomplish this in the mapping tool. I understand how to use conditional statements to determine whether or not to run an individual transform rule, however, the mapping tool does not want to map a complex type to a string, even though each individual element has a single value.

Any suggestions?

Here is the schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://NewPublishingXMLtoACORD" xmlns:ibmSchExtn="http://www.ibm.com/schema/extensions" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://NewPublishingXMLtoACORD" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <xsd:element ibmSchExtn:docRoot="true" name="operation1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="DOCUMENT">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="DOCSET">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>                                        
                                        <xsd:element name="TRANCODE">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="TRANCODE"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="STATUSCODE">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="STATUSCODE"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="DESC">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="DESC"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="LOCID">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="LOCID"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="SUBLOCID">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUBLOCID"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="JURISDICTN">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="JURISDICTN"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="TRNNAME">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="TRNNAME"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="QUEUEID">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                            <xsd:enumeration value="QUEUEID"/>
                                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                                </xsd:attribute>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="GUIDKEY">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                        <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                            <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:enumeration value="GUIDKEY"/>
                                                                </xsd:restriction>
                                                            </xsd:simpleType>
                                                        </xsd:attribute>
                                                    </xsd:extension>
                                                </xsd:simpleContent>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="WIPKEYS">
                                            <xsd:complexType>
                                                <xsd:sequence>
                                                    <xsd:element name="KEY1">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="KEY1"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="KEY2">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="KEY2"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="KEYID">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="KEYID"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="RECTYPE">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="RECTYPE"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="CREATETIME">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="CREATETIME"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="ORIGUSER">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="ORIGUSER"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="CURRUSER">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="CURRUSER"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="MODIFYTIME">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="MODIFYTIME"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="FORMSETID">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="FORMSETID"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="TRANCODE">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="TRANCODE"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="STATUSCODE">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="STATUSCODE"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="FROMUSER">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="FROMUSER"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="FROMTIME">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="FROMTIME"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="TOUSER">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="TOUSER"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="TOTIME">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="TOTIME"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="DESC">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="DESC"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="INUSE">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="INUSE"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="ARCKEY">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="ARCKEY"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="APPDATA">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="APPDATA"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="RECNUM">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="RECNUM"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="LOCID">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="LOCID"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="SUBLOCID">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="SUBLOCID"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="JURISDICTN">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="JURISDICTN"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="TRNNAME">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="TRNNAME"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="QUEUEID">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                        <xsd:enumeration value="QUEUEID"/>
                                                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                                                </xsd:simpleType>
                                                            </xsd:attribute>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="GUIDKEY">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                    <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:enumeration value="GUIDKEY"/>
                                                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                    </xsd:attribute>
                                                                </xsd:extension>
                                                            </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="CUSTOMKEYS">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                                <xsd:element name="KEY">
                                                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                                                        <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                            <xsd:extension base="xsd:int">
                                                                                <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                            <xsd:enumeration value="UNIQUE_ID"/>
                                                                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                                                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                                </xsd:attribute>
                                                                            </xsd:extension>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                                                </xsd:element>
                                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>
                                        <xsd:element name="FIELD" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                                <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0">
                                                    <xsd:element name="P">
                                                        <xsd:complexType>
                                                            <xsd:sequence>
                                                                <xsd:element name="FONT" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                    <xsd:complexType>
                                                                        <xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                                                                                <xsd:attribute name="FACE" use="required">
                                                                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                                                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                                                            <xsd:enumeration value="Helv"/>
                                                                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                                                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                                                                </xsd:attribute>
                                                                            </xsd:extension>
                                                                        </xsd:simpleContent>
                                                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                                                </xsd:element>
                                                            </xsd:sequence>
                                                        </xsd:complexType>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                    <xsd:element name="BR">
                                                        <xsd:complexType/>
                                                    </xsd:element>
                                                </xsd:sequence>
                                                <xsd:attribute name="NAME" use="required">
                                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                                            <xsd:enumeration value="AGENTADDRESSCITY"/>
                                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                                </xsd:attribute>
                                            </xsd:complexType>
                                        </xsd:element>                              
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this task by first creating a for each mapping from FIELD to the individual string I was mapping to on the other side. Then, underneath that nested map, I created an if mapping from FIELD to the individual string I was mapping to with a condition property set to "$FIELD/@NAME = 'namedInsured'". Finally, underneath that nested map, I mapped from the "mixed" variable under the FIELD element to the individual string field I wanted to map to and everything worked out!